# FB Graph Api - search in group feed

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have a closed FB group and I can get post of it via FB Graph API

```
$postResult = $this->facebook->api("/GROUP_ID/feed", "GET",);
```

But I wanna find post with some "search string" now. I tried

```
$postResult = $this->facebook->api("/GROUP_ID/feed", "GET", array('query' => "SEARCH_STRING"));
```

and

```
$postResult = $this->facebook->api("/GROUP_ID/search", "GET", array('query' => "SEARCH_STRING"));
```

but it still not work. Is there some way to search in group posts?

Answer (score 4):

You can't do that. You can use the Search API only with the endpoint `/search`. The format for searches is:

```
GET graph.facebook.com
  /search?
  q={your-query}&
  [type={object-type}]
```

Check out the available search types here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api#searchtypes

The `/{object-id}/search` or any other format is not allowed.

You can loop through all the results and do searching at your end.